# How to select two values in one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-insert

Seems extremely basic, but I can't find an elegant solution to it. I have two SQL tables, say one contains the users, and the other one, the cities. A third table contains the matches between the two previous tables (with two foreign keys pointing to each of the tables' PKs.)

I want to add an item to this third table to tell that the user Jeff lives in Boston, MA.

Right now, this is what I do:

```
INSERT INTO users_countries
SELECT user_id, city_id FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 user_id
    FROM users
    WHERE name = 'Jeff' AND ...
) a JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 city_id
    FROM cities
    WHERE name = 'Boston' AND ...
) b ON 1 = 1;
```

While this does the job, it doesn't look elegant at all.

What would be a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't join 2 unrelated tables.
You want to add new row to the table which consists of 2 **totally unrelated values**.
You are looking for elegance where you should be looking for efficiency first.
Why do you use a join? Even then, why an `INNER` join when a `CROSS` join would do without setting any conditions?
I would use `VALUES` and not `SELECT` and a totally unnecessary `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO users_countries(user_id, city_id) VALUES
(
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 user_id FROM users
    WHERE name = 'Jeff' AND ...
  ),
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 city_id FROM cities
    WHERE name = 'Boston' AND ...
  )
);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00f9b0392f57e062d2f7021ed4c53553).

Answer (score 2):

I think a more typical method would be:

```
INSERT INTO users_countries (user_id, city_id)
    SELECT user_id, city_id
    FROM users u JOIN
         cities c
         ON u.name = 'Jeff' AND 
            c.name = 'Boston' ;
```

This should not return duplicates.  But if you want to ensure one row, then use `SELECT TOP (1)` in the `SELECT`.